# How to get raw text from MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I have a MaskedTextBox with this mask (999) 999 9999.
When user inputs a number the text property would give this to me :

```
(0881) 444 5445
```

But I want to save the raw text to database field like this: `08814445445`.
How can I do that?

Comment: strip the mask manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on what I found [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?661357-RESOLVED-How-do-i-get-the-VALUE-of-a-MaskedTextBox&s=2958be9d816b6d4ea9c63a3b632622b0&p=4072069&viewfull=1#post4072069) you can set the `TextMaskFormat`-Property to `MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals`. That should be you solution.

The `MaskFormat`-Enumeration holds some "options" for the MaskedTextBox.
They are:

1. `ExcludePromptAndLiterals` Return only text input by the user.
2. `IncludeLiterals`   Return text input by the user as well as any literal characters defined in the mask.
3. `IncludePrompt` Return text input by the user as well as any instances of the prompt character.
4. `IncludePromptAndLiterals` Return text input by the user as well as any literal characters defined in the mask and any instances of the prompt character.

The default is 
`IncludeLiterals`

Answer (score 4):

It's Work for me

Just Change Property Value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `maskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat` property to
`MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals`

Comment: "Try" without explanation should be comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10482320)

Comment: @swidmann This does provide an answer to the question. Trivial questions that can be easily answered by reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.textmaskformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) often may have trivially looking answers.

Comment: @GSerg, I agree the text from review does not fit 100%, but I miss some explanation in this answer